# Why is cell formatting not displaying correctly until second attempt?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel sheet generated by SSRS and occasionally exhibits a strange cell formatting issue.

Top level rows, 1 in column A, are highlighted with a fill color as shown in picture below.  Occasionally, on these rows, the cell in column C for that row shows up white fill.

[image]

If I right click that cell and select *Format Cells...* it shows the correct pattern color despite it displaying as white.

If I select the cell and use the immediate window to output `ThemeColor` or `Pattern` they both return a value of `-4142` which is not correct.

```
Debug.Print Selection.Interior.ThemeColor
```

Now if I set the cell fill color once it doesn't change anything including the output from immediate window test.

If I set the cell fill color a second time it changes and everything works as expected.

So I have two questions...

1. What is happening to that cell that it won't even respond to setting properties (on first try)?  What is controlling it's state?
2. Is it initiating from SSRS or Excel?

---

Here is a [link to the file](https://nofile.io/f/9AxaNjdQc3W/BOM+-+Stripped.xlsx) hosted on NoFile.io

---

Following @Schlebe advice I compared a fixed sheet with original xml.  The differences between the original and fixed cell was the s value.

Original: `<c r="C125" s="5"/>`

Fixed: `<c r="C125" s="4"/>`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug.

Try to post it on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?ppud=4

You must certainly give more explanation or submit your Excel file.

But what is your SQL server version ?

What is your excel file type ? xls or xlsx ?

If xlsx, your can try to open Excel file using 7z and compare the orignal file with file that you have corrected.

To do that

1. you extract each element in a folder
2. under Notepad++ with XML
       tools, you format all XML files to split each tag on one line
3. using
       WinMerge, you compare each files in both folders.

It is possible that StyleId are changed and that doesn't facilitate the comparaison. So it is possible that you must save the file a first time without adding some change and you must compare the 2 saved files.

Normally, I will add a comment, but I have too much to write and it is easier to use an Answer to format correctly a big message :-)

Comment: Thanks for the info Schlebe.  I added a link and will try your suggestion later today.